# I want to compute the Maximum Likelihood Estimator of a density but my output produces NaN's when mathematically my equations are correct

Tags: r, statistics

I think my code is "almost correct", but why do I get NaN's?

```
N=100


est1 = function(m){



  tau = rep(0,m)

  b0 = rep(0,m)

  b1 = rep(0,m)

  tau[1] = 1

  b0[1] = 1

  b1[1] = 1

  x<- runif(100,0,1)


  for(i in 2:m){

    tau[i] = N/tau[i-1] + sum(log(y)) -(1 + exp(b0[i-1]+b1[i-1]*x) )*sum(y^tau[i-1]*log(y)/(1+y^tau[i-1]))  

    b0[i]= N - log(  1 +y^tau[i-1] )*sum( exp(b0[i-1]+b1[i-1]*x))

    b1[i] = (sum(x) )-log(1+y^tau[i-1])*sum( x*exp(b0[i-1]+ b1[i-1]*x ))

  }

  cbind(tau,b0,b1)
}

output = est1(100)

output
```

Comment: You should a) explain what you are trying to do more fully and b) in particular explain what `y` is supposed to be (if it's not jsut a typo).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they can be mathematically correct, because you never defined `y`!